# An error occurs when HUAWEI Scan Kit executes the startScanFromFragment method

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I tried integrating the HMS Core Scan SDK into my Android Studio project. During compilation, a message was displayed indicating that the name of libnative-lib.so conflicts with the name of a third-party library. How to resolve such a name conflict?

```html
*what went wrong
Execution failed for task':appV5:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForMidea_out_teseDebug".
>More than one file was found with OS independent path "lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the HMS Core Scan SDK contains a library named libnative-lib.so, which has the same name as the third-party library you've referenced in your project. We'll resolve this issue in later versions.